# Unable to choose an installation profile on a multi-site installation

Tags: 8, multi-sites, installation-profiles

I installed drupal 8 with the open social installation profile using composer. Now I want to turn this drupal install into a multi-site installation where some of the other sites don't use this installation profile. But when creating a new site (I know how to do this from my D6/7 days) I can't select an installation profile. Instead the Open Social installer is always run and it's installation profile always gets applied. 
I figured out it is probably due to the vendor stuff that composer does when installing drupal and open social. It changes some things in the vendor folder that change the drupal 8 installation procedure. But the question that remains is if it is possible to still use this install with the standard drupal installation profiles.

Or a perfectly acceptable alternative for me would be to make a base install of drupal8 and afterwards add the opensocial installation profile so I can still choose my installation profiles. I guess that would mean ditching composer? Or maybe not? I don't really know because I am not familiar with how composer changes the drupal workflow from the way I used to work with it in d6/7.

Comment: I'd recommend against using multi-site. It's not complicated to manage separate sites and far more reliable. You can only update drupal core and shared modules for them at the same time and when you need different versions that it's going to get complicated.

Comment: I have my reasons for wanting a multi-site setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the .info.yml file, do no put `distribution` statement, ss mentioned in [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-distributions/how-to-write-a-drupal-8-installation-profile) guide:

```
# Optional: Declare your installation profile as a distribution
# This will make the installer auto-select this installation profile.
# The distribution_name property is used in the installer and other places as
# a label for the software being installed.
distribution:
  name: Distribution Name
```

Comment: You're right, but those are docs on creating a profile while I just want to install one :). BUt it indeed worked. I still needed to figure out how to deal with composer and profiles together, but I got it working. I'll do a write-up somewhere because it is not that straight forward.

Comment: Remove that statement?